# Capturando o valor boolean de uma checkbox em PHP

Tags: php, post, inserir

Estou fazendo um formulário de produto, onde o usuário precisa informar se o produto é ou não usado, porém estou tendo dificuldades em capturar o valor dessa `checkbox`, se é `1` ou `0`, no `mysql` a coluna já está setada como `boolean` com `default 0`

logica-adiciona-produto.php

```
 <?php
    include("conecta.php");

    #Variáveis para cadastrar
    $nome = $_POST["nome-produto"];
    $preco = $_POST["preco-produto"];

    $descricao = $_POST["descricao-produto"];

    #Caso de verificação da variável booleana
    $usado = $_POST["usado-produto"];
    if(array_key_exists($usado, $_POST)) {
        $usado = "true";
    }else{
        $usado = "false";
    }

    #Query de inserção
    $query = "insert into produtos(nome, preco, descricao, usado) values('{$nome}', '{$preco}', '{$descricao}', {$usado})";

    #Variável para executar a inserção
    $retornoInsercao = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

    #Teste para verificar inserção
    if($retornoInsercao){
        header("Location:index.php");
        die();
    }else{

    };

?>
```

adiciona-produtos.php

```
<?php
    include("header.php");
    include("conecta.php");
?>

 <form action="logica-adiciona-produto.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome-produto">
        <label>Preço:</label>
        <input type="number" name="preco-produto">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Usado ?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="usado-produto" value="true">
        <label>Categoria:</label>
        <select name="">

        </select>
        <label>Descricao:</label>
        <textarea name="descricao-produto"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit">
    </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: 1 e 0 mesmo !!! 1 para `true` e 0 para `false`

Comment: continua recebendo como 0 no banco

Comment: Se está dizendo do código! neh?

Comment: mesmo quando marco a checkbox, ele registra como false no servidor (0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu código está errado, está enviando uma variavel que não condiz com o nome da chave, observe:

*Troque:*

```
#Caso de verificação da variável booleana
$usado = $_POST["usado-produto"];
if(array_key_exists($usado, $_POST)) {
    $usado = "true";
}else{
    $usado = "false";
}
```

*por isso:*

```
$usado = array_key_exists('usado-produto', $_POST) ? 1 : 0;
```

*Explicação:*

*A estrutura da função* `array_key_exists`

```
bool array_key_exists ( mixed $key , array $array )
```

onde o ***primeiro*** paramentro é o nome da chave a buscar dentro do `array` e o ***segundo*** o `array` propriamente, que retorna verdadeiro (`true`) ou falso (`false`) no resultado, se encontrou ou não ...

ou também

```
$usado = isset($_POST['usado-produto']) ? 1 : 0;
```

<sub>***Referencia:*** [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-key-exists.php)</sub>

Comment: queria algo aproximado com o que eu fiz, pois o professor no curso usou o mesmo método que eu estou utilizando

Comment: @MuriloGambôa é o primeiro código `array_key_exists`, não é isso ? só lembrando que você colocou os paramentos errados, ou seja, estava fazendo errado...

Comment: o professor no curso usou basicamente isso >

`<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="usado" value="true"> Usado
</tr>`
...
`$usado = $_POST['usado'];

if(array_key_exists('usado', $_POST)) {
    $usado = true;
} else {
    $usado = false;
}`

Comment: `'usado'` é diferente de `$usado` e outra coisa se o seu professor ensinou `$_POST['usado'];` sem conferir se existe também é uma prática errada, cuidado.

Comment: Você esta passando a variável como parâmetro do "array_key_exists" o que você deveria passar é o nome da "key" que você está querendo verificar se existe.

Comment: @JhonnyRogerVirgiliodaSilva foi o que eu relatei, na resposta.